# What's the stability of VS2010 like?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stability

I'm talking about VS 2010 Professional/Ultimate RTM (not express versions).
Google doesn't show much other than stuff about the beta 2 and RC versions.

Will it run OK on a Core 2 Duo E6550 2.33GHz with 3GB RAM and NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS?

**Edit:
How does it go with R# 5.0?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stability: Good

SVN Support (using ankh): Good

2008 to 2010 project upgrade: Good.

No reason not to upgrade.

The only thing is that it requires 3 restarts on XP and 1 on 7...

Answer (score 3):

I've been using the Premium RTM daily since release and experienced no problems whatsoever developing with C#/ASP.NET MVC2.

My machine is also similar specs to yours and has been running just fine.

Regarding your edit, I've also been doing all of this with Resharper 5.0 - again, no problems whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

I haved runed it for since release now, and i must say i have had no problem at all, but hey diden't have any with VS 2008 ether. But evythings works great fast and all this while looking nice :D Eclipse go home .D

Answer (score 2):

I installed VS 2010 Ultimate RTM, in my laptop and its specs is exactly like yours except the Nvidia, and it is working perfectly with no problems.

Answer (score 2):

I've been very impressed with 2010.

Even the Beta and RC releases were stable.  I find VS2008 SP1 hanging on average twice a day for me.

So far the only thing to crash 2010 was a third party plugin.

Comment: I am in the opposite situation. With WPF I had some occasional crash with VS2008. Now with VS2010 it happens 5/6 times per day that it hangs for 30 seconds or more before reacting again.

Comment: Thats annoying.  I don't do much in WPF at all, so I'm luckily avoiding that issue.

Comment: Marco - it would be great to know why VS crashes for you. Here are some initial tips: http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/02/08/how-to-investigate-and-report-visual-studio-issues.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I was running the RC for a few months before the RTM version was released, and even the RC version was rock solid as far as I was using it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't use a stopwatch but I got the impression that it is a bit slower at startup than its predecessor.

Comment: It is - because we spin up the CLR and WPF (and we didn't in Orcas). Good news is that we won't have to do that later, so you pay the price upfront once.